# Can't Create Android Virtual Device. OK Button disabled

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I can't create a new AVD in Eclipse. I've tried doing it using the AVD Manager.exe (basically out of Eclipse) and as you can see I have CPU/ABI options yet no matter what I do the OK button is disabled

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the "skin" option is left blank. In order to create an emulator, you'll need to choose one.

Comment: This should be a comment i think.

Comment: @Ragnar It answers the question. A comment would be more like a suggestion, but I know what you mean.

Comment: I think it may be the right answer, @Ragnar. I don't see anything else. I guess you meant that adneal could provide more context ;)