# Can't create AVD - "OK" button disabled- Eclipse Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I am trying to create AVD from last two days. I have referred the following links:

- [The "OK" button is deactivated in creating new AVD](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/70285/the-ok-button-is-deactivated-in-creating-new-avd-although-i-have-provided-all)
- [AVD cannot be created Ok is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821081/avd-cannot-be-created-ok-is-disabled)
- [Can't Create Android Virtual Device. OK Button disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144699/cant-create-android-virtual-device-ok-button-disabled)
- [Android Studio: “Ok” button disabled in “Create new AVD” window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609085/android-studio-ok-button-disabled-in-create-new-avd-window)

I have all the required file for creating AVD but still the`OK` button is disabled. I have installed the following list from Android SDK Manager

[image: Installed Packages through Android SDK Manager]
[image: I have installed all the <code>Extra</code> files and library]
[image: And Creating AVD]

Now where I have done mistake?? Is there any other thing which I need to install or delete file(s) to create AVD?

Comment: uncheck `Use Host GPU` and try.

Comment: Also try 'ARM EABI' not 'Android TV ARM' with a device like 'Galaxy Nexus' which is a handset.

Comment: I have tried Galaxy Nexus  in Device and ARM(armeabli-v7a) in CPU/ABI and it works fine after restarting the PC... Thank you for your great answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart PC and again try to create AVD by following this instruction:

- Select Galaxy Nexus in `Device`
- Select ARM(armeabli-v7a) in CPU/ABI
- Uncheck `Use Host GPU`

This works fine for me. Hope this help you as well

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes usually when

- Your CPU/ARM field is not supported. Try changing this field and check